# How to select result form two tables in django

Tags: django, django-models

How to select result form two tables in Django

My model is as follows,

```
from django.db import models
from apps.admin.product.models import Product

class Cabinet(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    cabinet_name = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cabinet'




class ProductCabinetConstruction(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, blank=True)
    cabinet_construction = models.ForeignKey(Cabinet, null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'product_cabinet_construction'
```

I would like to execute mysql query as follows,

```
SELECT DISTINCT (cabinet.cabinet_name), product_cabinet_construction.product_id FROM product_cabinet_construction, cabinet WHERE product_cabinet_construction.product_id = 33
```

and tried as

```
models.ProductCabinetConstruction.objects.select_related().filter(product=productObj.id)
```

but fails....any idea what's wrong with me

Comment: What fails? `pcc = ProductCabinetConstruction.objects.select_related("product").filter(product__id=productObj.id)` should work. You then have access to `pcc.product` if you want access to that object. `select_related` doesn't effect the result, it just helps to make the query more efficient

Comment: try this `models.ProductCabinetConstruction.objects.values('cabinet_construction__cabinet_name').filter(product__id=productObj.id).distinct()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code not working.... there  is no error in that code that code will return a queryset which contain a list of ProductCabinetConstruction you must loop this queryset for getting each element

I think you didn't use loop for getting each element

```
pcc = ProductCabinetConstruction.objects.select_related().filter(product=33)
```

just loop like this for getting each elements

```
for productcc in pcc:
    pro = productcc.product #is the product
    cab = productcc.cabinet_construction  # is the cabinet
```

Comment: But my mysql query- "SELECT DISTINCT (cabinet.cabinet_name), product_cabinet_construction.product_id FROM product_cabinet_construction, cabinet WHERE product_cabinet_construction.product_id = 33" will return all cabinet_name if it is not present in cabinet_construction. and if we switch it to django it return only common values from cabinet and cabinet_construction :(

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
ProductCabinetConstruction.objects.select_related('product', 'cabinet_construction').filter(product__product_id=33).distinct('cabinet_construction__cabinet_name')
```

or

```
ProductCabinetConstruction.objects.values('cabinet__cabinet_name', 'product__product_id').filter(product__product_id=33).distinct('cabinet_construction__cabinet_name')
```